# "Intends" or "Is intending"

Tags: present-tense

In this sentence "He intends to take a sledgehammer to it" I used the progressive but according to my book it is the wrong choice. Sometimes both the simple present and the progressive are possible. Do you think I can use "is intending" in my sentence? Exercise 4. Sentence #7
I uploaded the screenshot for more context.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "intends" is the better choice there. There's nothing  to suggest that the intention is transitory, since King actually bought the van for that express purpose.

Comment: So it's not an action with limited duration, is it? And if it was another verb for example "consider" or "think" it would not be wrong to use the progressive? "He is thinking of  or "is considering taking a sledgehammer" . Right?

Comment: Even with another verb, I think the simple present would fit better. You might say "he is thinking of.X" if he might change his mind, but that's not the case in this example. You could use the progressive, but it isn't called for.